# Any concerns about this iOS approach to responding to a long-running, async web call?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, ios8

I wrote a PHP function that sleeps 6 seconds (on purpose) to simulate my server taking a long time to respond back to my Swift app. I wanted to gracefully handle this in Swift and this is what I came up with. Any thoughts or concerns about this? Could it be improved upon?

Th function connects with a service I wrote called ContentWebService - this makes an async post to the server, and then responds accordingly. When you click the button, I disable it and make it say 'loading' (this is a proof of concept i'll use localized strings later) but basically I want to prevent the user from clicking it again (without disabling it, I was able to fire off a dozen requests which I think isn't great).

While the script sleeps / response comes back, you can go through the rest of the app and do your thing, but no matter what wherever you were the message will eventually come back and say it was successful.

Looks good??

```
@IBAction func btnSlow(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.enabled = false //sender is the button - set disabled as it gets clicked
    sender.setTitle("Loading, please wait..", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    ContentWebService.SlowFunction()
        { (r) -> () in

            if (r.Status == ResponseCode.SUCCESS) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.presentViewController(AlertCreator.ShowSimplePopup("Done", message: "Completed successfully.."), animated: true, completion: nil)
                    sender.enabled = true //reset back to enabled
                    sender.setTitle("Click for Slow Function", forState: UIControlState.Normal) //restore original text
                }
            }
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.presentViewController(AlertCreator.ShowSimplePopup(StringHelper.GetLocalizedString("UnknownError"), message: StringHelper.GetLocalizedString("UnknownErrorMessage")), animated: true, completion: nil)
                    sender.enabled = true //reset back to enabled
                    sender.setTitle("Click for Slow Function", forState: UIControlState.Normal) //restore original text
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: You do not have to say `(r) -> () in`. It is enough to say `r in`. - And please don't start a function name with a capital letter!

Comment: Thanks so much Matt. Appreciate the advice. In Swift is it typical to do functions as camelcased but the first letter lowercased?

Comment: Yes, camel casing is normal internally. There are some C functions whose names start with a capital, but in general if you use capital for types (classes etc. `CamelCase`) and lowercase for variables and methods (`camelCase`). Otherwise your code looks strange and can be a little hard for some of us to read. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're doing in that code is standard asynchronous callback procedure. My only suggestion is that you should consider some sort of timeout guarantee if you don't have one already.

(Note that it could be reasonable to prevent the user from navigating anywhere if you need to. You could turn off the interface's responsiveness to taps before the call to  `ContentWebService.SlowFunction` and turn it back on when you're called back in the anonymous completion function.)

Comment: This is what I was looking to hear, thanks so much. In your opinion what is a good road to go down to establish a timeout guarantee? This is exactly what I wanted to investigate. Is there a way to put a default timeout on my web request layer? i'm using NSMutableURLRequest. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you see, if you're using NSURLSession all this is done for you. You can specify a timeout, and _it_ does the callbacks for you.

Comment: so explore NSURLSession instead of NSMutableURLRequest? otherwise I'd have to set nsmutableurlrequest's timeout?

Comment: Both. NSURLSession takes an NSURLRequest. But if you use NSURLSession, yes, my understanding is that you should use _its_ timeout (in the configuration), not NSURLRequest's timeout which is left over from earlier incarnations.